# Get enum value from JSP submit buttons to struts2 action class

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, enums, struts2

I Have a Enum Class As Below

```
public enum Foo {
    A("a"),
    B("b"),
    UNDEFINED("UnDefined");
    private String foo;
    foo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    public foo safeValueOf(String foo) {
        for (Foo value : values()) {
            if (value.name().equalsIgnoreCase(foo)) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return UNDEFINED;
    }
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

And calling this enum in Action class.

I have one JSP which has 2 buttons. the code as below

```
<s:set var="fooval" value="%{@com.util.Foo@A}"/>
                                <s:submit value="%{fooval}" id="fooval" name="fooval" onclick="choose(this.id);"/>

<s:set var="fooval" value="%{@com.util.Foo@B}"/>
                                <s:submit value="%{fooval}" id="fooval" name="fooval" onclick="choose(this.id);"/>
```

Javascript code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
            function chooseTreatment(value){
                alert(value+document.getElementById("fooval").value);

            }
        </script>
```

When any of the button is clicked, In Javascript I am getting the value of A but not B if I click on second Button.

And action class:

```
private String fooVal; 
public String execute() throws Exception {

        System.out.print("fooVal....."+fooVal);

        return "success";
    }
```

Also, In action class I am unable to get the id value from JSP.

I am not getting what I am missing here.

Comment: Post the code for javascript

Comment: the values have the same id

Comment: yeah. but I have to get in one property in action class

Comment: use different values for id